# $\mathbb{C}(x)$ as a representation of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ an algebraic linear group. A representation $V$ of $G$ is a vector space such that the application $\phi : G \to GL(V)$ is defined.

**Definition** Let $G$ a linear algebraic group. A representation $V$ is locally regular if and only if $\forall W$ vector subspace of $V$ there exists a finite dimensional vector subspace $W'$ such that $W \subseteq W'$ , $W'$ is $G$-stable and $\phi : G \to GL(W')$ is regular (as an application between affine varieties).

Let $G = \mathbb{C}$ and $V = \mathbb{C}(x)$ a representation with the action $\phi: G \to GL(V)$ defined as follows: $\forall g \in G$, $\phi(g) : f(x) \to f(x -g)$, with $f \in V$. I want to prove that $V$ is not locally regular. My idea is to choose $W = \mathbb{C}$ and to find $W'$ finite dimensional vector subspace which is not $G$-stable, but I can't think of any. I tried looking for subfields of $\mathbb{C}(x)$, but they are all infinite dimensional. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\Bbb{C}$-vector space
$Span(\{ \frac1{x-a},a\in \Bbb{C}\})$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: But the definition requires the subspaces to be finite dimensional

Comment: $W$ is finite dimensional and $W' = \Bbb{C}[G].W$ is infinite dimensional

Comment: I must have forgotten to specify that $W'$ must be finite dimensional, I just edited It.

Comment: Again I took $W$ finite dimensional and got $W' = \Bbb{C}[G].W$ infinite dimensional.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{C}[G]$? Also, I still don't understand how taking $W'$ infinite dimensional can serve as a counterxample. Could you please detail it a little bit?

Comment: I am taking $W$ finite dimensional, the smallest $G$-stable subspace ($*$) containing it is infinite dimensional. ($*$) ie. the subspace generated by the $g.W,g\in G$

Comment: I mean I can see why the vector space in your answer is infinite dimensional and it is $W'$. Who is $W$?

Comment: Make a guess ? ${}{}{}$

Comment: I don't know, is it $\mathbb{C}$? If so, why is $W'$ the smallest $G$-stable subspace containing it?

Comment: The smallest $G$-stable subspace containing some element $f$ is the one generated by the $g.f, g\in G$. The $f$ in my answer is obvious, $G =\Bbb{C}$ acts through shifts.

Comment: Oh, ok. So $W$ is the subspace generated by $\frac{1}{x}$. Thank you.